# Prove that there is some points $x_0$ in the interval $[a,b]$ at which $f(x_0)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Suppose that the continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=0$. Prove that there is some points $x_0$ in the interval $[a,b]$ at which $f(x_0)=0$.

---

Proof:

Since $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=0$, there exists a partition sequence $\{P_n\}$ such that $$\sup\{L(f,P_n)\}=\inf\{U(f,P_n)\}=0$$ Now apply the extreme value theorem since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, there exist $x_i,x_j\in\{P_n\}$ where $i\neq j$ satisfy $$f(x_j)\leq\sup L(f,P_n)\}=\inf\{U(f,P_n)\}\leq f(x_j)$$ Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, there is a $x_k\in\{P_n\}$ where $k\neq i\neq j$ such that $$f(x_i)\leq f(x_k)\leq f(x_j)\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;f(x_k)=0$$

---

Can someone check this solution? I am not sure this is right or not. If this is not right, can someone give me a hint or suggestion to write a better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is almost fine. I think you mean $x_i, x_j \in [a, b]$, not the set of partitions; likewise with $x_k$.

---

For a different approach, note that if $f$ did not have a zero, it has constant sign by the intermediate value theorem. If the sign is positive, then $L(f, P) > 0$ for *all* partitions $P$, which immediately implies that $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx > 0$. If the sign is negative, work with upper partitions.

Answer (score 5):

And another approach: let $F(t) = \int_{a}^t f(x) d x$. Then $F(a) = F(b) = 0$ so by  [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) there exists $x_0 \in (a,b)$ such that $F'(x_0) = 0$.  But $F' = f$.